# Host="null" in file transfer xmpp

Tags: java, xmpp, file-transfer, openfire, smack

I received this packet from client:

```
  <iq id="dgl8K-24" to="admin@localhost/testchat" from="tp@localhost/testchat" type="error">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"
           sid="jsi_8684670244487833690"
           mode = "tcp">
      <streamhost jid="proxy.localhost" host="null" port="8086"/>
    </query>
    <error code="404" type="CANCEL">
      <item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
      <text xml:lang="en" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Could not establish socket with any provided host</text>
    </error>
  </iq>
```

Why is host null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error stanza, that contains a copy of the request that caused the error as per [RFC 6120, section 8.3.1, point 6](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-error-rules).  That means that you sent the original stanza containing `host="null"`, and you got an error reply because the other client couldn't connect to host `null`.